# Sass - Can I target multiple label based on it's 'for' entry?

Tags: html, sass

I want these label use same style. How to do it in Sass?

```
<label for="origin">Origin</label>
<label for="destination">Destination</label>
<label for="date">Date</label>
<label for="train">Train</label>
<label for="dep.">Dep.</label>
<label for="arr.">Arr.</label>
<label for="class">Class</label>
<label for="coach">Coach</label>
<label for="seat">Seat</label>
<label for="price">Price</label>
```

Comment: Can't you target all the `label`'s, or add a classname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to target those `for` values, you could define a list of the available values and use `@each` to loop over them to create the CSS you need:

Example, using the first 4 values:

```
$values: "origin", "destination", "date", "arr.";

@each $for in $values {
    label[data-for="#{$for}"] {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }   
}
```

Will generate the following CSS:

```css
label[data-for=origin] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label[data-for=destination] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label[data-for=date] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label[data-for="arr."] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Now I use className to target it instead, but thank you for knowledge :D